# Using int16h to read shift+arrow

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm, dosbox

I am using TASM assembly to write a program and within that program I am listening to a user's keypress. I would like to listen to when a user holds down the shift and the arrow key. However, it seems like that that combination has neither a unique scan code nor a unique ascii character. Is there a way to listen to this combination or would it be more practical to just use ctrl+arrow key, as they do have a unique scan code?

Thank you

Comment: If you're reading scancodes, you should be able to track the state of the shift keys yourself.

Comment: *...it seems like that that combination has neither a unique scan code ...* how did you decide that? If you're using `int 16h` then have you looked at the documentation for it? Look at, for example, the case where `ah = 02h`.

Comment: I have my program printing out the scan codes of the keyboard buttons I press and pressing shift seems to have no effect on the scan code.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for arrow key press and when it is pressed check the state of the shifting keys (which are Ctrl, Alt, Shift). If you fill both requirements you have just catched user pressing the combination.